# SQL IF statement Issue

Tags: sql

What's wrong with my SQL statement?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE prGetDocById
    @Nbr varchar(100),
    @Type uniqueidentifier,
    @TotalRecord int output
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@Type is null)
    BEGIN
    (
        SELECT @TotalRecord = COUNT(Category) FROM Document where Nbr = @Nbr and 
            Type = (case when @Type IS not null then @Type else null end) 
        SELECT * from Document
    )
    end
    else
    begin
    (
        ...
    )
    end
end
```

it gives me this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure prGetDocById, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure prGetDocById, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure prGetDocById, Line 19
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I want to start with `IF` statement and need to return the output too, so there will be two select statement in my statement.

If I write it without `IF` statement, everything is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should follow the structure:

```
IF( 1 = 1) BEGIN
    SELECT 1;
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT 2;
END
```

There are curly braces in your second condition which aren't legal and the parenthesis aren't legal/necessary (at least not in MS SQL Server) in the first condition body other than in specific circumstances.

### Parenthesis Usage

```
-- legal but pointless most of the time
IF( 1 = 1) BEGIN
(
    SELECT 1
)
END

-- illegal
IF( 1 = 1) BEGIN
(
    SELECT 1;
)
END

-- illegal
IF( 1 = 1) BEGIN
(
    SELECT 1
    SELECT 2
)
END
```

### Specific Query

*I don't understand the logic here (the `CASE` seems pointless), but I think this is syntactically correct. Note that I put `[Type]` in brackets as it is a reserved word.*

```
IF( @Type IS NULL ) BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @TotalRecord = COUNT(Category) 
    FROM Document
    where Nbr = @Nbr and [Type] = (case when @Type IS not null then @Type else null end);

    SELECT * from Document;
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT 0;
END
```

Comment: @kevin you don't need the brackets for the IF statement

Comment: @kevin - I added your specific query.